# How to get selected checkbox value

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I have implemented a Names with a check box in a List, Here my aim is to check the check box and get the respective name. Here i have written code in adapter and in activity class but i am not getting any value and it is not showing any errors.

Here my adapter code..

```
public Add_member_adapter(Context a, ArrayList<ItemsModel> d) {

        context = a;
        data = d;

        checkedHolder = new boolean[data.size()];

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    public int getCount() {
        if (data.size() <= 0)
            return 1;
        return data.size();
    }


    public final Object getItem(int position) {
        return data.get(position);
    }

    public final long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {

        public TextView Name, UserId_Fk;
        CheckBox chkbox;

    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        Log.d("getview:", "position=" + position);
        vi = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {

            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_members_list_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.Name = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.Name);
            holder.UserId_Fk = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.CusId_Fk);
            holder.chkbox = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.chkbox);

            vi.setTag(holder);
        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();

        }
        if (data.size() <= 0) {

            vi.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        } else {

            tempValues = null;
            tempValues = (ItemsModel) data.get(position);

            holder.Name.setText(tempValues.getItemName().toString());
            Log.i(TAG, "Name " + tempValues.getItemName().toString());
            holder.UserId_Fk.setText(tempValues.getUserId_Fk().toString());
            holder.chkbox.setChecked(false);

            holder.chkbox.setChecked(checkedHolder[position]);
            Log.i(TAG, "Position " + checkedHolder[position]);

            holder.chkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                boolean isChecked) {

                            checkedHolder[position] = isChecked;

                            Log.i(TAG, "Position " + checkedHolder[position]);
                        }
                    });

        }
        return vi;
    }
```

In Activity...

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                // String Name = list.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                // CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chkbox);
                // TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Name);

                for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {

                    if (adapter.checkedHolder[i]) {
                        // get all name values that checked by user
                        Name = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.Name)).getText()
                                .toString();
                        Log.i(TAG, "Name " + Name);
                    }
                }

            }

        });
```

Comment: First of all, what is the super class of your adapter? Why do you return 1, when your data list is empty? You don't have to hide view in `getView()` if list empty also.

Comment: and provide your code for ItemsModel

Comment: Ok i will change that and can u guide me why checked values are not coming

Comment: @ravichandra before  holder.chkbox.setChecked(false) line you have to set holder.chkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null)

Answer (score 0):

change your setOnItemClikListener as below

```
for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
      if (adapter.checkedHolder[i]) {
             // get all name values that checked by user
             Name = data.get(i).getItemName().toString();
             Log.i(TAG, "Name " + Name);
}
```

in `getView` relpace `holder.chkbox.setChecked(false);` with below line ;

```
holder.chkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
```

Comment: i can't take getItemName()

Comment: data in the sense your ArrayList<ItemsModel>